# Solving Rosenthal's Example using Undergraduate Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This example is based on the example given in *A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory* by Rosenthal. Suppose we have a Poisson random variable $X$ with mean $\lambda > 0$. That is,

\begin{align}\mathbb{P}\left(X=x\right) = \dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x}}{x!}
\end{align}

Suppose also that $Y \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, 1\right)$. That is,

\begin{align}f_{Y}(y) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^{2}/2}\text{, } y \in \left(-\infty, \infty\right)\text{.}
\end{align}

Flip a fair coin and consider a random variable $Z$. If the coin flips heads, $Z = X$. If the coin flips tails, $Z = Y$.

How can one calculate, for example, $\mathbb{E}\left[Z\right]$?

**Possible Solution**: Let $W = 1$ if heads and $W = 0$ if tails, both with probability 1/2. Then

\begin{align}\mathbb{E}\left[Z\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[Z | Z = X\right](0.5) + \mathbb{E}\left[Z | Z = Y\right](0.5) \\
&=  0.5\lambda + 0.5(0) \\
&= 0.5\lambda\text{.}
\end{align}

Is there anything wrong with this solution? Note that I have very little background with graduate probability theory, so any explanation as to what I am wrong is appreciated.

**Second Question** (as given in comments): Rosenthal skips over the calculation of $\mathbb{E}\left[Z^{2}\right]$ because he wants to make a point that $Z$ is neither discrete nor continuous. Can a similar method be employed as in my proposed solution?

Comment: Seems right :) Perhaps it would be more usual to write $E[Z] = E[E[Z|W]] = E[Z|W=0]*P(W=0) + E[Z|W=1]*P(W=1) = E[X]*P(W=0) + E[Y]*P(W=1)$.

Comment: You are right due to linearity of expectation: $\mathbf{E}[X+Y]=\mathbf{E}X+\mathbf{E}Y$

Comment: Do we run into problems in computing $\mathbb{E}\left[Z^{2}\right]$?

Comment: We find $E(Z^2)$ in the same way.